# Including c libraries in the custome code section of Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm trying to include `Csparse` from `SuiteSparse` in to Simulink.
I've included the header `ch.h` and the directory of the c-functions in the custom code section.
 If I call the function `cs_compress` over `code.ceval` I get this error:

```
cs_compress.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cs_spalloc referenced in function cs_compress 
Test2_sfun.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x460' 
Stop.
```

The function `cs_spalloc` I presume is called from a library since there exists no `cs_spalloc.c`. The function is however defined in the  header file as:

```
cs *cs_spalloc (csi m, csi n, csi nzmax, csi values, csi triplet) ;
```

Am I right to presume it is called from a library?
And if so where do I find the library in a format to include in to the custom code section in Simulink?

Answer (score 0):

I found the c- functions `cs_spalloc` online, and just copyed it. Now it works.